# jQuery Star Rating Plugin with ASP.Net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins

Hi I'm using the jQuery Star Rating Plugin from http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/#tab-Testing which works great, but I need to get the rating value that is displayed in the the div 'hoverstarresult' when the user clicks upon a rating using a .Net function.

```
Protected Sub Btn_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Response.Write(hoverstarresult.InnerHtml)
End Sub
```

The above function always returns an empty value. Any ideas? Thanks for any help

Here is the star rating code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.hover-star1').rating({
                focus: function (value, link) {
                    var tip = $('#hoverstarresult');
                    tip[0].data = tip[0].data || tip.html();
                    tip.html(link.title || 'value: ' + value);
                },
                click: function (value, link) {
                    var tip = $('#hoverstarresult');
                    $('#hoverstarresult').html(tip[0].data || '');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>


 <input class="hover-star1" type="radio" name="test-3B-rating-1" value="1" title="Very poor"/>
 <input class="hover-star1" type="radio" name="test-3B-rating-1" value="2" title="Poor"/>
 <input class="hover-star1" type="radio" name="test-3B-rating-1" value="3" title="OK"/>
 <input class="hover-star1" type="radio" name="test-3B-rating-1" value="4" title="Good"/>
 <input class="hover-star1" type="radio" name="test-3B-rating-1" value="5" title="Very Good"/>
 <div id="hoverstarresult" runat="server"></div>
```